# Show that the field extension is not Galois.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\alpha$ be complex with $\alpha^2 = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5}$. I need to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Galois extension.

Any hints would be very welcome.

Comment: Maybe you could try to find the irreducible polynomial with $a$ as a root and then find its splitting field and show that the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ is strictly greater than the degree of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Is $x^8 - 16x^2 + 4$ the *minimal* polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 5$ over $\Bbb Q$?  How do we know?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis A valid concern! We have $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\sqrt5)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^2)\subset \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. This implies that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree that is a multiple of four. But $\alpha$ is not real, so not an element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$. Therefore the degree of the minimal polynomial is eight.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. thanks for coming through for me Jyrki!

Answer (score 1):

Try this argument:

The polynomial $f(x)=x^8-16x^4+4$ clearly has precisely four real roots (one for each of the (two) real fourth roots of the zeros of $x^2-16x+4$). Thus the field gotten by adjoining one root of $x^8-16x^4+4$ has four real embeddings, two (pairs of) complex embeddings. But a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ has all real embeddings, or all complex.

Comment: A simple argument!